# Basic HTTP Authentication for a Middleman app

Tags: ruby, http-authentication, middleman

I wonder whether there's an easy way to add Basic HTTP Authentication to a Middleman deployed website? I found some Heroku specific gists, but nothing else.

The Heroku specific gists all seem to need a `config.ru` file, but do Middleman projects even have such a file? Mine don't.

Comment: As you may have guessed, I already tried that. Didn't succeed.

Answer (score 0):

`config.ru` is not specific to Middleman or Heroku, but is a convention for serving a rack-based app (see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rack). If you want to have basic auth on a static site that you have built using middleman and then deployed, you will need to set it up in a way that's appropriate to that hosting. Where are you hosting the site?